# How does current flow in this circuit with multiple power regulators?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ground, buck, boost, modeling

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbRGTj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U1 contains two voltage regulators (Vo1=+10V, Vo2=-10V, input Vin=5V). (These could be buck, boost etc. but I *think* it is not important for the question)

Vo1 acts as voltage supply for the load (think of it as "VDD") and Vo2 as return path (think of it as "VSS"), so mostly Io1=Io2. (Note: I added D1 and GND just to show that there other other signals going into LOAD where (smaller) currents may flow, so Io1 may not be exactly Io2).

I am interested what Iin and Ignd current looks if I know Io1 and Io2.

**Example:** Say Io1, Io2 is a square wave with Ilow=0, Ihigh=1A and period 1kHz. Switching frequency is 10MHz. Conversion efficiencies 100% for simplicity. How would Iin/Ignd look like if I apply a 100kHz lowpass filter (so I can ignore switching/ripple)?

How is such a circuit analyzed?

Comment: Ignoring switching ripple, that's just DC, is that what you expect? It would help writing a better answer if you would explain you own view.

Comment: It's like saying, ignoring the ingredients, how do I make a pizza.

Comment: @Justme Yes, that's the question I want to answer: Without ripple, Is Ignd/Iin just DC, even though ILoad has 1kHz frequency component? If I model Vo1/Vo2 with a voltage source, then this is the case but it doesn't sense to me: This current needs to come from somewhere (=Iin). If I do LTspice sim using ADP2503-5.0 as an example, I see the 1kHz in in the spectrum of Iin/Ignd (besides the switching harmonics).

Comment: @Andyaka No that's not a good comparison. If you want, add in switching and ripple. Look at my example: ILoad draws 1A current at 1kHz. Switching is 1MHz. Then look at the spectrum of Ignd and Iin and and apply a lowpass filter with fc=100kHz. What does the spectrum look like? (EDIT: Changed the question to "How to make pizza with ingredients" if that's easier to understand)

Comment: @divB Now you changed the specs. Of course if you specify that load takes current at 1 kHz frequency then it does so. For each DC current value out at any given time there is a matching DC current value in at any given time, no matter if the time frame is 1 hour or minute or 1 millisecond.

Comment: @Justme I did not mean to change the spec, I wrote from the beginning "Example: [...] and period 1kHz". Can you explain why it's visible in Ignd/Iin? U1 right now is a black box to me and hard to grasp for me how the currents actually flow. That's why I am asking for a model (preferably a linear model) that helps me to understand this.

Comment: @divB when I wrote my comment, there was no mention of anything running at 1 kHz, it was added in later.

Comment: How are you with [this teardown](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383289/bidirectional-buck-boost-converter-vs-separate-buck-and-boost-converters/383293#383293) of a buck-boost converter? Does it need to be simpler?

Comment: @Justme: Sorry for this. I made a few changes right after I posted. Must have happened before I saw your post.

Comment: @Andy aka: In know in principle how a Buck/Boost on its own works. But here I have two of them with load in between and both driven by the same input supply. The question is really more about circuit analysis rather than how a Buck/Boost works exactly. That's why I am asking about an easy model. Justme's answer goes in the right direction although I am still not 100% sure about it.

Comment: @divB I don't see a load in between in your diagram - I see a load connected to terminals marked Vo1 and Vo2 - if that is "somehow in between" then please explain and, if necessary make your diagram much clearer (somehow). If you are saying that Vo1 is the output of a buck circuit and Vo2 is the output of a boost converter then, they are independent circuits and, it doesn't really help to call them a buck/boost regulator - A buck/boost regulator is how the circuit in my link is.

Comment: @Andyaka I reworked the diagram and added some explanation. Is the question more clear now?

Comment: Not anything in your diagram tallies with a buck regulator. It shows a boost regulator and an inverting regulator. It could even imply a flyback converter. Nothing is making sense. Sorry dude, I've done my bit but, if you want to convince someone that you'll recognize a good answer when you see it, you need to demonstrate consistency between words and picture in your question.

Comment: @Andyaka I have removed (nearly) all references to buck/boost, if this is what confuses you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to this problem is to treat both outputs as two separate DC/DC regulators, connected in parallel.

Of course, contrary to what the comments suggest, it *is* possible to model each regulator with an ac/small signal model that ignores the switching. With a feedback loop, this concept is very similar to PLL modeling.

The book **Fundamentals of Power Electronics** by D. Erickson derives models to various degrees of accuracy, based on a canonical model (i.e., identical structure for different types of converters).

In the simplest case, the converter (open loop) can be modeled with a simple (DC) transformer (or, equivalently with controlled voltage/current sources). This model is sufficient for OPs question: A current in the secondary winding of a transformer (load current) results in a current in the primary winding based on winding ratio (here: duty cycle or voltage ratios).

The model can be extended to include losses (inductor and switch losses), dynamics and finally a feedback loop.

As to the numerical example with the square wave: With zero load current, there is no input current. With Io=1A, twice the current will flow in the primary winding of the first converter and with Io2=1A, 2A will flow in the primary winding of the second converter. So in total 4A.

Now we can confirm that power is conserved. At the input: Pin=5x4=20W. At the output: Pout=P1+P2=1x10 + (-1)x(-10)=20W.

Answer (score 2):

Just think power in at any given moment matches power out. Including the losses that make the efficiency to be less than 100%. A first order assumption might ignore losses for simplicity.

If your load takes in power at 1 kHz rate, then the power supply must give out this power at 1kHz rate so there is constant voltage with current varying at 1 kHz rate. Which means the power supply will has to take in power at 1 kHz rate too.

Even simpler approximation could also ignore the 1 kHz and assume it's that some average DC power out equals to average DC power in.

Comment: Great, I think this is exactly what I am looking for. Specific to the example, is this correct then? Given: ILoad (1kHz rect waveform 0A-1A) and all voltages (Vi=5V, V1=10V, V2=-10V). Po1=10*ILoad. Po2=-10*(-ILoad). Pin=Po1+Po2=5*Iin. --> Iin=4*ILoad ? So Ignd **and** Iin is 1kHz rect waveform between 0A and 5A (plus any switching noise added by the converter)?